# How to get data from an API in Lua and save it

Tags: json, lua

The API I want to get data from is: https://api.playhive.com/v0/game/all/wars/player.

After I successfully make a request I just need the `xp` value. I want to save that value.

The website will return data that looks like this:

> {"UUID":"4214a39f-68bf-3dac-afa7-4fcd896d90bc","xp":148821,"played":604,"victories":325,"first_played":1633534354,"final_kills":1191,"kills":2183,"treasure_destroyed":1323,"deaths":889}

I tried

```lua
network.get("https://api.playhive.com/v0/game/all/wars/sebwx"
```

but I really have no idea about network stuff.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a value from a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342771/how-to-read-a-value-from-a-json-file)

Comment: "I tried ```network.get```" That is not vanilla Lua. Where/how are you running this code? Roblox? Love2d? Some other runtime? That will be important to know, because vanilla Lua does not have any built in JSON parsing, but maybe your runtime does.

Comment: `local xp = to_number(your_json_string:match('"xp":(%d+)'))`